# can not get vuex state using Cypress

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, cypress, quasar-framework

I am following [this blog](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/#Store-to-UI-and-server-API). The window.app property does appear in the console after adding the code as described, however I can not reference `app.$store` ans mentioned in the blog (and which resembles the way to reference the store within components). I can reference `app.store` which indeed contains properties from my vuex store, but it does not contain the `app.store.state`, just the getters (and dispatches etc.).

E.g. using  `const getStore = () => cy.window().its('app.store')` it gives:

[image: screenshot from 2018-04-26 09-27-25]

I would prefer to be able to have state variables available directly and not only the once I made a getter for. What's wrong? Is this because I use namespacing in my vuex store?

EDIT:
It might also relate to my way of assigning the store to the window. I use Quasar Framework, which in current version (>0.15) does a lot of configuration based on the settings in the `quasar.conf.js` file it uses. I assigned the store by adding this code as a [quasar plugin](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html):

```
export default ({ app, store, Vue }) => {
  if (window.Cypress) { // should only be available during E2E tests
    window.app = app
  }
}
```

Doing so gives me indeed the `app.store` I mentioned, but not `app.$store` (including `state`). Quasar config is generated and shown in a file, which after adding this plugin contains:

```
/**
 * THIS FILE IS GENERATED AUTOMATICALLY.
 * DO NOT EDIT.
 *
 * You are probably looking on adding initialization code.
 * Use "quasar new plugin <name>" and add it there.
 * One plugin per concern. Then reference the file(s) in quasar.conf.js > plugins:
 * plugins: ['file', ...] // do not add ".js" extension to it.
 **/
import './quasar'
import Vue from 'vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false
import 'quasar-app-styl'
import 'src/css/app.styl'
import App from 'src/App'
import router from 'src/router'
import store from 'src/store'

const app = {
  el: '#q-app',
  router,
store,
  ...App
}

const plugins = []

import pluginCypress_vuex_store from 'src/plugins/cypress_vuex_store'
plugins.push(pluginCypress_vuex_store)

import pluginVuelidate from 'src/plugins/vuelidate'
plugins.push(pluginVuelidate)

plugins.forEach(plugin => plugin({ app, router, store, Vue }))

new Vue(app)
```

As you can see the plugins are part of initialising the Vue app, whereas the way the blog and you suggest it, it is attached after the Vue initialisation. As Quasar autogenerates the config I do not know how to do 'window.app = app' after the initialisation to see if this causes my issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same on my Vue application. See this [section](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2017/11/28/testing-vue-web-application-with-vuex-data-store-and-rest-backend/#UI-to-store)

> Before we write a test, we need to decide how to get to the store reference. To allow testing and controlling the application through the Vue instance I prefer to keep a reference to the component on the window object. In the app.js, set window.app for testability.

```js
const app = new Vue({
  store,
  el: '.todoapp'
  //
})
window.app = app
```

The last line is the key, when I add that the test code works as advertised.

Note, the file to adjust may be **main.js** rather than **app.js**.

---

### Quasar - Special App Plugin: Boot

Ref [this doc](http://quasar-framework.org/guide/app-plugins.html#Special-App-Plugin-Boot), you can achieve the correct Cypress `window.app` reference by generating this special plugin, then changing it to

```js
export default ({ app, Vue }) => {
  // do some logic here...

  // ... then, kick off our Quasar website/app:
  window.app = new Vue(app)
  // "app" has everything cooked in by Quasar CLI,
  // you don't need to inject it with anything at this point
}
```

Note, this is not a standard quasar app plugin.

Comment: I tried to do that already. As I use Quasar Framework this needs to be done differently. Maybe that's causing my issue. I added an EDIT to my question to give more details on that.

Comment: Aaah, the Special App Plugin: Boot was added somewhat later I think! It works, excellent! Thx!

Comment: To have the property just in Dev I did: ```export default ({app, Vue}) => {
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.app = new Vue(app)
  }
  else {
    const vue = new Vue(app)
    vue()
  }
}``` which works but gives error in normal (not Cypress) browser: 'boot.js?5fa4:7 Uncaught TypeError: vue is not a function
    at __webpack_exports__.a (boot.js?5fa4:7)'; When I just do ```new Vue(app)``` I get linting error saying 'Do not use 'new' for side effects  no-new'.

Comment: This makes it work exactly as I would like it to without any errors: ```export default ({app, Vue}) => {
  if (window.Cypress) {
    window.app = new Vue(app)
  }
  else {
    (() => new Vue(app))()
  }
}```

Comment: For what it's worth, that linting error occurs in a non-quasar Vue app as well. I use `/* eslint-disable no-new */` to clean it up.

Comment: 1. Using ```window.app = app``` is brutal, 2. You modify your production code just in order to make your tests work. No way :)